# Socket.io with Create-React-App - Connection_Refused Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, create-react-app

This is my first time working with Socket.io. I am trying to bring it into an app bootstrapped with `create-react-app` but am hitting some `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` issues.

**server.js**

```
const io = require('socket.io')();
const port = 8000;

io.on('connection', (client) => {
  client.on('subscribeToTimer', (interval) => {
    console.log('client is subscribing to timer with interval ', interval);
    setInterval(() => {
      client.emit('timer', new Date());
    }, interval);
  });
});

io.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port ', port);
```

**api.js**

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');

function subscribeToTimer(interval, cb) {
  socket.on('timer', timestamp => cb(null, timestamp));
  socket.emit('subscribeToTimer', 1000);
}
export { subscribeToTimer }
```

**component**

```
class Root extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      timestamp: 'no timestamp yet'
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    subscribeToTimer((err, timestamp) => this.setState({ timestamp }));
  }

  render() {
    return ( <p>{this.state.timestamp}</p> );
  }
}
```

Whenever I run `yarn start` and check my console, the interval is running correctly, however, instead of logging the timestamp it is repeatedly showing the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error.

I am running locally on `localhost:3000`.

Is there additional setup needed when using `create-react-app` to get this integrated?

Thank you.

Comment: Within `api.js` your `connect` doesn't specify where to connect. Which in your case should be `http://localhost:8000`. `const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000');`

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my code and the original post but I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: You need to include `server.js` within an `express` app and start it separately. https://expressjs.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your `server.js`, are you running it separately from the `yarn run start` command?  If not, that would cause the ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

When I run the processes separately, I'm receiving an error from your supplied code.  It turns out you're missing the interval for the `subscribeToTimer()` call.  Changing your `componentDidMount` to something like

```
componentDidMount() {
  subscribeToTimer(100, (err, timestamp) => this.setState({ timestamp}));
}
```

should solve the issue.